# Overlapping anchors on hover state

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown for my navigation in my mobile view. I am having an issue with the anchors overlapping. I attempted to stack them on top of one another by setting the display to block and adding a margin-bottom.

This has not worked as you can see.

**html**

```
  <div id="brand">
    <h1>brand</h1>
    <nav>
      <div class="fa fa-plus"></div>
      <div class="fa fa-cog">
        <a href="#">Edit Profile</a>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </div>
      <div class="fa fa-sign-out"></div>
      <input type="search" id="main-q" name="q" placeholder="Search" data-value="" value="">
    </nav>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
nav .fa a {
  display: none;
}

nav .fa:hover a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#brand {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
  background: white;
  color: darkgrey;
  padding: 1em;
}

#brand h1 {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tqkjvmyj/)

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine. The main problem was to setting the `position: absolute` for`a`. Simply wrap those anchors  `a` in `UL li` and then set the position for `UL`.

CSS:

```
nav .fa .child { /*modified CSS*/
  display: none;
  border:1px solid red;
  }

nav .fa:hover .child { /*modified CSS*/
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fa fa-cog">
    <ul class="child"> <!--class child for dropdown-->
        <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tqkjvmyj/5/)**

Comment: This is excellent. One question. What is the best way to get this working on mobile?

Comment: You can use media queries for responsive design.